# Swap top and bottom 2 bits for each row/col in an int[][] Array using bit operators JAVA

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, bitwise-operators

I need to take some array and exchange the bottom 2 bits with the top 2 bits for each [row][col], and I am pretty lost. I found a similar thread on here with this bit of code:

```
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {

        int pic = image[row][col];
        int top  = (pic & 0b11110000) >> 2;
        int bottom = (pic & 0b00001111) << 2;
        pic = top | bottom;
        image[row][col] = pic;
    }
}
```

and it almost seems to work, but isn't quite right. Additionally, I do not understand this portion: 0b00001111 at all.

I found that code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331213/how-to-do-certain-things-to-2d-images), that thread seems to be the exact same problem that I am working on....like including the other code. The instructions I was given are:

"Calling swap restores an image in which each pixel has been scrambled by exhanging the bottom 2 bits with the top 2 bits. To do this requires that your code do the same exchange to restore the image.
NOTE: The maximum value of a pixel (Picture.MAXVAL) is 255, so only 8 bits are valid for each pixel. These are numbered bits 0-7, where bit 0 is equal to 1 and bit 7 is equal to 128. There are no negative values allowed."

Comment: What is the type of image?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Can you put an example?

Comment: the `0b00001111` one part is performing a binary and (notice its a single & instead of two, against pic), the 0b prefix appears to be a new feature in Java 7 for writing binary.

So it appears your swapping the bottom and top 4 bits (nibbles), rather than simply 2 bits of the least significant byte (ints are 4 bytes not 1).

Comment: Reading your question, are you mistaking bits and bytes? because it sounds like you wish to swap around 4 bytes which make up an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, it appears you are mixing up bits and bytes. An integer is 4 bytes, which is 32 bits.

```
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        int mask = 0b11111111_11111111_00000000_00000000;

        int pic = image[row][col];
        int top  = (pic & mask ) >> 16;
        int bottom = (pic & ~mask) << 16;
        pic = top | bottom;
        image[row][col] = pic;
    }
}
```

---

If you do actually want to swap the top 2 bits with bottom

```
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        int maskTop = 0b11000000_00000000_00000000_00000000;
        int maskBottom = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000011;
        int pic = image[row][col];
        int top  = (pic & maskTop) >> 30;
        int bottom = (pic & maskBottom) << 30;
        pic = top | bottom | (image[row][col]&~(maskTop+maskBottom));
        image[row][col] = pic;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested either of these, but they look right.

Comment: Ok, so apparently for this specific program, only the first 8 (0-7) are relevant. So I would do 

int maskTop = 0b11000000;
int maskBottom = 0b00000011;
int top  = (pic & maskTop) >> 7;
int bottom = (pic & maskBottom) << 7;

Comment: Works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Since Robadob has already answered, I will clear out some questions for you:

In Java, you can write numbers in:

- decimal way (`int x = 26` => decimal 26),
- hexadecimal way (`int x = 0x1A` => decimal 26),
- binary way (`int x = 0b11010` => decimal 26)

When manipulating bits and bytes like in your example, sometimes is very useful to write a bit mask for bitwise operations using `0b...` notation. Again, see Robadob's answer.

When he does this: `int top  = (pic & mask ) >> 16;` it means that he took all the bits of the `pic` integer and did **bitwise and** (`&`). Then he shifted them 16 places to the right (int has 32 bit places). So the top 16 bits were all set to 0 and bottom 16 bits were set to 1 or 0 (depending what was there before). He did opposite for bottom and then he did **bitwise or** on those two numbers (he combined top and bottom).

**EDIT: After all the comments and communication, here's a working solution:**

```
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {

        byte maskTop = 0b11000000;
        byte maskBottom = 0b00000011;

        byte pic = image[row][col];
        byte top  = (pic & maskTop) >> 6;
        byte bottom = (pic & maskBottom) << 6;
        pic = top | bottom | (image[row][col] & ~(maskTop+maskBottom));
        image[row][col] = pic;
    }
}
```

Comment: right I understand that, but so if I want ONLY the top two bits of that byte I would do int foo = (x & 0b11000000)

Comment: @lexlcon An int is 4 bytes, not 1 byte.

Comment: @lexIcon No... You need 0b11... and then 30 zeros. `int` has 4 bytes = 32 bits. But you also need to merge the concatenated top and bottom together with inner 28 bits (this part of Robadob's answer: `| (image[row][col]&~(maskTop+maskBottom));`)

Comment: yes, I see that. I've updated my op with some relevant instructions that I just found: 

"The maximum value of a pixel (Picture.MAXVAL) is 255, so only 8 bits are valid for each pixel."

Comment: Then better use `byte` as your type, and not `int`. And then use Robadob's solution (just modify the bit masks to 8 bits and change shift (>> 30 and << 30 to >> 6 and << 6) .

Comment: @lexIcon I added a working solution. Hopefully your problems are now resolved! If you got more questions, do ask.

Comment: upvote, thank you for the detailed information, I actually understand this now!